# JS - How Web Workers work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this code :

**JS**

```
<script  src='file://C:\blablabla\JavaScript\bignumber.js-master\bignumber.js'></script>
<script>
    document.write("<h1>\"blabla\"</h1>\n<h3>blabla</h3>");

    function problem(){
        var img = document.getElementById('problemi');
        return img.style.display = img.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    function problem551(){
        problem();
        var t0 = performance.now();
        var max = 1e+15;
        var sum = new BigNumber(1);
        for(var i=1;i<max;i++)
            sum = sum.plus(scomponi(sum,0));
        var t1 = performance.now();
        document.getElementById("p551").innerHTML = 'blabla<span>'+max+"</span> blabla <span>" + sum +"</span> in <span>"+(t1 - t0)/1000+"</span> blaaa"; 

    }

    function scomponi(num,sum){
        var str=num.toString();
        for(var i = 0 ; i< str.length ;i++ ){
            sum += parseInt(str[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }


</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="problem551()" >PROBLEM 551</button>
        <img id="problemi" src="PROBLEM551.png" style="display: none;">
        <p id="p551"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

But Chrome crashes, it gives me this :

[image: error]

How can prevent this error on my function, he has a loop from 1 to 1e+15, so it takes too much time. I read something about WEB WORKERS but is unclared for me. I want to use it on my function **problem551()**, so someone can explain me how it works?

Comment: Web workers are recommended for resource intensive tasks, not necessarially long running ones. First, you should see if you can improve the performance of your existing code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: In this case `var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");` if I want to use my function isteand of worker.js?

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do there?

Comment: Your function will need to be moved into a separate file that can be accessed with `.. new Worker()`

Comment: You pass a script url to the web worker. The worker executes the script on a separate thread.

Comment: Ah, you're working on [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=551)...

Comment: @Cerbrus yes I'm working on it in JS.. It looks to be impossible to do without math tricks

Comment: You're probably going to have to figure out some kind of formula, yea

Comment: I'm agree in that way by a c code I arrived at 10+e10 :/ ... I'm looking for some formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your functions to a new file, `funcs.js`:

And use `new Worker("funcs.js")` to start it.

You can use `postMessage` to send the result back as described in MDN:

> Sending messages to and from a dedicated worker
>
> The magic of workers happens via the postMessage() method and the
>   onmessage event handler. When you want to send a message to the
>   worker, you post messages to it like this (main.js):
>
> ```
> first.onchange = function() {
>   myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
>   console.log('Message posted to worker');
> }
>
> second.onchange = function() {
>   myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
>   console.log('Message posted to worker');
> }
> ```
>
> So here we have two  elements represented by the variables
>   first and second; when the value of either is changed,
>   myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]) is used to send the
>   value inside both to the worker, as an array. You can send pretty much
>   anything you like in the message.
>
> In the worker, we can respond when the message is received by writing
>   an event handler block like this (worker.js):
>
> ```
> onmessage = function(e) {
>   console.log('Message received from main script');
>   var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
>   console.log('Posting message back to main script');
>   postMessage(workerResult);
> }
> ```

Do expect it to still take a lot of time, it is quite a long operation, but it will hopefully prevent Chrome from bringing up the error.

---

I see you are trying to solve Project Euler problem 551.

You are throwing away a valuable piece of information:

> You are given a_10^6 = 31054319.

You don't need to begin your iterations from 1. The next number can any arbitary number in the sequence.

```
a_10^6 = 31054319

a_(10^6 + 1) = 31054319 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1 + 9
```

Comment: I dont understend your last part , what did u mean? sum+=scompose(sum) is not the same?Ok i can start with i=31054319, but it takes 1 sec to reach  this number with i=0..

Comment: @Teshtek My bad, I thought it would take a significant time to compute. http://eulersolutions.fr.yuku.com/topic/404/PE551 is an interesting thread.